# Writing a character to a file in C (mbed)?

Tags: c++, c, mbed

This is my code C/C++ code for writing a character to a file.

```
#include "mbed.h"

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
char c;
char *cha = &c;

int main() {
     FILE* WriteTo = fopen("/local/yourtext.txt", "w");

     pc.printf("Write something and then press enter when finished...\n\r");

     while (c != '\n') {
        c = pc.getc();
        pc.printf(cha);
        fputc(c, WriteTo);
     }

     fclose(WriteTo);   

     pc.printf("File write successfull.\n\r");
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work on my LPC1768. It only takes in one character and then I am unable to type anymore. I tried some other ways but none of the ways I tried allowed me to write to a file.

I'd like to also know if `getc()` empties out after I use putc. Does it have a limitation on the amount of characters I can write?

Comment: @UKMonkey I'm aware yes, I meant that this C++ compiler can compile C code, and so I am using C here.

Comment: What's the point of `wait(0.1);` btw?

Comment: @Lukali you should only tag with the language you're using - not what your compiler can support .... Just because my C compiler can compile pascal and fortran doesn't mean I should tag pascal and fortran to my C questions ;)

Comment: @Groo removed. Hopefully this helps bring focus to the real question.

Comment: @UKMonkey its more like... if there is a way that works/is better for writing to file in C++, I want to know it. I'm not interested in keeping it pure C.

Comment: @UKMonkey Yes, I am trying to just write the characters in with putc to a file, not read them? The reading takes place before and it isn't reading it from the file but the pointer to just typed char.

Comment: @Lukali yeah - I realised just after hitting enter ;)

Comment: What's the prototype of `pc.printf`? ... The instruction ` pc.printf(cha);` is not correct for sure, because cha is not a 0 terminated string.

Comment: What's the prototype of `pc.getc();`?

Comment: @SirJoBlack I don't know what you mean, this is one of the base functions? Maybe this helps: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/

Comment: The reference is the reason 'cause I ask you what's the prototype.  This is the prototype: `int getc ( FILE * stream );` ... Where did you declare the input stream (`FILE * stream`)? But I don't know what's the implemantation of getc prototype into the class `Serial` of your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pc.printf(cha);
```

`printf` needs `format` argument to be *`null`* terminated `char *`.
But you are passing non *`null`* terminated `char *` thus by invoking undefined behavior.

Use:

```
pc.printf("%c", *cha); //Or pc.printf("%c", c);
```

Comment: The issue still persists. I can only write one character after using 'pc.printf("%c", c)' instead of pc.printf(cha)

Comment: [Or simply `pc.putc(cha)`](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/apis/serial.html#serial-hello-world) (edit:) not 100% sure about that, though, the example I linked is for echoing back to the serial port, but `printf` to `FILE` should use some sort of `putc` under the hood.

Comment: @Lukali Are you pressing enter key after typing the letter? As you are breaking the loop once you press enter.

Comment: @kiranBiradar No I am just typing normal characters. I am using Tera Term VT to communicate with the board.

Comment: @Lukali You need to check return value of  `fopen` such that you are not operating on `NULL` file pointer.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Okay I forgot to put 'LocalFileSystem local("local");'. My enter key press doesn't get me out of the loop though. I tried c != 10, c != 0x0A and c != '\n'. Does the terminal enter key work differently?

Comment: @kiranBiradar Alrite it's value 13 not 10. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's always a good practice to keep a NULL check when using pointers.